# DirectX11 Quad in Screen Coordinates - C#/SlimDX

Tags: c#, slimdx

How do I place a quad on the near plane of the frustum at a particular point as defined by screen space?  I have the frustum corners and I've tried too many things to name them all but getting a quad at an exact point eludes me. especially if I move/rotate the camera at all. I've had some limited success in placing the center of the quads at a certain point but haven't been able to offset them so the corners are where I want them to be.

I'm using a perspective left-handed projection. About the only thing I haven't tried is going down the path of using a new Viewport with a fixed ortho camera and I'm starting to think I might go that way...

One of my closer failed attempts looks like this:

```
Vector3 bottomleftcorner = Vector3.TransformCoordinate(Frustum.Corners[1], viewProjection);
```

Where Frustum.Corners[1] is the Bottom Left Near corner.

Using that vector would put a quad center in the corner of the screen but I've been unsuccessful trying to offset it from center, which sounds a lot easier than I've found it to be simply because I don't know what 'half' is at that particular depth.  Also if I move the camera the quad starts moving around and I want it to be stationary. I'm not sure if it's fov that's throwing everything off or what?

Technically I don't require screen coordinates, I would be happy with anything where I could determine the corners of viewport and place an object at certain point within it. I assume there is a simple way of doing this that I have not yet been able to figure out.

Thanks.

One thing I forgot to mention is that these quads are instanced, so the position vectors are simply added to an identity matrix in the vertex shader. I don't think that should make it any more complex but it's probably worth mentioning.

Comment: Why don't you provide the coordinates in screen space in the first place? It seems to make no sense to convert from screen space to world space when creating the quad and from world space to screen space in the vertex shader. If you cut both transformations, you should be fine. Otherwise, take a look at `Vector3.Unproject`. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks. So I created a new shader where I basically ignore view and projection transformations and I'm now able to place the quad quite easily where I want it. Great! Only thing is now my UV is all buggered up and the color is broken.  At least I'm making progress here. Any quick thoughts on why the texture would be all messed up?

Comment: Hm, no idea. The texture should not be affected by a different calculation of the vertex position. Impossible to tell without a screenshot and the code. But that belongs in another question if you don't find the problem.

Comment: Sorry, that was completely unrelated. This solution worked for me.  Using a new shader and ignoring view/projection.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Nico. This lead me to discovering a problem I didn't even know I had in my shader where i was basically adding an extra 1.0f to the .w part of a float4 causing nothing to work right. In the process I learned something new, and discovered a problem I didn't even know I had.  Win Win. Thanks again.